# The problem of reading Japanese characters in TeXStudio's PDF viewer

Tags: pdf, texstudio, japanese

The Japanese characters written in my work can be read by Adobe

[image]

but not by the pdf viewer

[image]

What is this problem?

Comment: Can you please add some code to reproduce the problem?